# Duplicating typedefs inside nested C++ class

Tags: c++, class, typedef

Is there a better way for declaring the same typedef inside nested class or another way for making the type accessible from the nested class ?

```
class A {
public:
    typedef vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator const_it;
    class B {
    public:
        //regular way with code redundancy
        typedef vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator const_it;
    };
};

int main() {
    A::const_it it1;
    A::B::const_it it2;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I know that const_it is visible from B, but i want to make it accessible through B from outside (e.g. A::B::const_it)

Comment: Hint: `A::const_it` is visible in `B`

Comment: yes i know, but you can't access it through B (e.g. A::B::const_it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find `typedef A::const_it const_it;` more palatable in place of your `typedef` in the definition of class `B`.